# laravel-excel Undefined index: $

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-excel

I try to import and show details in blade php

If comment this section, there's no error

```
$results = Excel::load('files/' . $file_name, function($reader){
        $reader->all();
    })->get();
```

i want to read and display the details from excel sheet to blade template
here is my code:

```
public function ImportClients(){

    $file = Input::file('file');
    $file_name = $file->getClientOriginalName(); // save the file name
    $file->move('files/', $file_name); // file moved successfuly

    $results = Excel::load('files/' . $file_name, function($reader){
        $reader->all();
    })->get();

//  return view('clients', compact('results'));
}
```

This is the error msg:
[check the image for error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Eg7P.png)

Comment: Sounds like the string contains `$` on either 0 or 1 (`$something`). `$pString{0}` or `$pString{1}` would be `$`, which doesn't exist as a key.  You'll have to check the contents of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
     if ($request->file('excel')!==null) {
 $inputFileName = $request->file('excel')->getRealPath();
 $spreadsheet = IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
 $data = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, true, true, true);
```

and then return view with data

Comment: <form action="ImportClients" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <label>upload file: </label> <br />
   <input type="file" name="file">
   <input type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" name="_token">
   <input type="submit" value="upload">
  </form>

Comment: //Route::get('ExportClients', 'ImportExcelController@ExportClients');
Route::post('ImportClients', 'ImportExcelController@ImportClients');
Route::get('upload', 'ImportExcelController@upload');

Comment: well you need add public function ImportClients(Request $resquest){